# Determine if algorithm is infinite for the pair of positive integers $(n,m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, binomial-coefficients

Given any pair of positive integers (n,m) and the following algorithm:

```
The smaller integer(n) doubles and the bigger one(m) becomes `m-n` until m is equal to n

Example: 
    (7,1) -> (6,2) -> (4,4) - Algorithm is finite
    (21,9) -> (12,18) -> (24,6) -> (18, 12) - Algorithm is infinite
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1**. Proof that the algorithm ends if $m+n = 2^k \gcd(m,n)$ by induction on $k$.

First notice that for any $m,n \in \Bbb N, {m\over2} + n + {m\over2} = n+m$ thus $n+m$ is a loop invariant. What's more $m+n = 2\gcd(m,n) \implies m=n$. This is our base case.

Now assume $m\lt n$ and $m+n = 2^k\gcd(m,n)$ for a certain integer $k\ge2$.

Then $$\begin{align}
\gcd(2m, n-m) &= \gcd(2m, n+m)\\ 
&= \gcd(2m, 2^k\gcd(n,m))\\ 
&= 2\gcd(m, 2^{k-1}\gcd(m,n))\\ 
&=2^i \gcd(m,n)
\end{align}$$
for a certain $i\ge1$.

Therefore $m+n = 2^{k-i}\gcd({m\over2}, n+{m\over2})$ and since $k-i \lt k$, the algorithm finishes (note that $k-i \gt 0$).

**2**. Proof that the algorithm ends only if $m+n = 2^k \gcd(m,n)$ by structural induction.

Note that the solutions can be constructed by induction by :

- $n,n$ is solution for any integer n
- $m,n$ where $n\gt m$ is solution iff $2m, n-m$ is solution.

If $m=n$ then $m+n = 2\gcd(m,n)$, this is our base case.

Lets assume that the algorithm ends for a certain pair $\{m,n\}$ where $n+m = \gcd(m,n)2^k$ for a certain integer k, then the preceding pair was necessarily $\{{m\over2},n+{m\over2}\}$ or $\{{n\over2},m+{n\over2}\}$. Let's assume the latter without loss of generality (since $n$ and $m$ play a symmetrical role).

Then $2^i\gcd({n\over2}, m+{n\over2}) = \gcd(m,n)$ for a certain integer $i$ (see above) and therefore ${n\over2} + m + {n\over2} = 2^{k+i}\gcd({n\over2}, m+{n\over2})$.

Therefore any pair $\{m,n\}$ for which the algorithm finishes satisfies $\exists k \in \Bbb N^*, m+n = 2^k \gcd(m,n)$

**Conclusion** the algorithm finishes for $n,m$ iff $\exists k \in \Bbb N^*, m+n = 2^k \gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: You can reach the pair $\bigl(\frac{k}{2}, k + \frac{k}{2}\bigr)$ also from $\bigl(k - \frac{k}{4}, k + \frac{k}{4}\bigr)$.

Comment: Indeed you can, ... I'll edit my answer and give this some more thinking, thanks !

Comment: The idea with powers of $2$ is however something you should not forget.

Comment: The algorithm finishes if and only if $m + n = \gcd(m,n)\cdot 2^k$ for some positive integer $k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean, could you please explain?

Comment: @luleksde I edited my answer